# How to FTPS upload file instead "save" in Windows application

Tags: windows, ftps

Is there a way how to upload files from Windows applications directly to an FTPS server? I use Photoshop and I would like to FTPS upload jpeg file to my hosting FTPS server instead of "save" to local disc.

Now, I have to

- save the file to my PC
- upload the file with Total Commander
- delete the local file

Possibility of direct FTPS upload would speed my work,

I am using Windows 7, there is possibility to define FTP connection, but it is not secure (it is FTP, not FTPS).

Swish - http://www.swish-sftp.org/ is **nearly** what I need, but it is for SFPT, not FTPES.

Is there a way? How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you use WinSCP (http://winscp.net/) you can browse the remote directory and open files. If you open an image file with photoshop and save it to the same file it opened it from then it will detect changes and automatically upload the new version. The local file will be automatically stored in a temp directory so you don't have to worry about that.
WinSCP supports FTPS

Comment: Thank you! It is very interesting, but unfortunately it doesnt solve my problem, because I do not edit remote file. The file is created in Photoshop, so I need to upload new file.

Comment: @swisst Ah I see, sorry, I assumed you were editing existing files. I believe WinSCP has a sync feature, I don't have much experience in it but if you setup automated sync between a local and remote folder then you can save to the defined local folder and hit sync. It may take a bit of setting up but you can read about it here. [link](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_synchronize_full)